# How to remove title in add new form.aspx

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer

How to remove title from SPD in add new form.aspx. My list name is search.when i add new item it shows search - New Item, On edit it shows search - Title.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to List Settings -> Advance Settings -> Allow Management of Content Types radio button to Yes

[image]

Then click Item Content Type in List Settings -> click Title -> Hidden (will not appear in forms)

[image]

It will save you from editing List Form using SharePoint Designer 2010

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide dialog title:

[image: NewForm.aspx title]

you should add "display:none;" to the css of `.ms-dlgTitle`
you can find it here:

```
body.v4master div.ms-dlgContent div.ms-dlgBorder div.ms-dlgTitle
```

in my css file it's on the 7606 string. You also can set css on the page of the form in spd

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ms-dlgTitle
  {
     display:none;
  }
</style>
```