# How to hide webpart header name

Tags: web-part

I have a list named as "Search". When i add a new item web part header as "Search - New Item". On edit item header as "Search-title". How to remove the header for all forms (Add new item/ edit item / View item)

Comment: Are you talking about the displays settings of a web part here? Its generally set in the 'Chrome Type' - you might not be however

Answer (score 0):

You have already asked this question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49659/how-to-remove-title-in-add-new-form-aspx/49663)

The guy below me has answered it, you can hide it using proper css...

In chrome, you can see what css is used by header name - right click the header name and click Inspect Element to see css used.. Or in Internet Explorer use Developer's Toolbar (F12)..